# How to find people to play Magic the gathering with?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I started playing Magic about six years ago, and I live in a very "Intelligence Deficient" Town. I have tried playing online and I Don't have a game shop nearby. Help me please??????

Answer (score -5):

It's illegal, but you can always play for free on cockatrice or mws (never tried mws). Look the link in mtgsalvation.com forum (im typing from mobile).

You can also play on mtgo, which is legal, but i think doesn't worth it.

You can also ask your friends to play it too.

Good luck